# Divide page into regions separated by rules above and below

Tags: rules

I'd like to divide a page into a number of cards. Each card is a rectangle of size, say, text width times 5cm. Each card should be surrounded by hrules on both sides. This means the first card on the page should have a rule on top, the last card on the page should have a rule at the bottom, and adjacent cards should be separated by a single rule. Rules are used for physically cutting the page into cards, and all cards should have the same size.

I can create cards using minipage. However, if I place a rule at the bottom of the card, the first card on the page lacks a rule on top. If I have rules on both sides of the card, then the rule between cards is doubled.

Comment: Why not using a simple  tabular environment? Who provides the text? You? Which kind of text?

Comment: This could work, but preferably cards should have the same height and I want the document to be automatically split into pages (a card should not be split.) My document consists of a number of environments

`\begin{card}
Some text
\end{card}`

I provide the text in cards. It's some problem statement for a test.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the highly configurable `tcbraster` environment from `tcolorbox`, applying the `raster equal height` option.

The `cardbox` environment is used to display the raster item and can contain 'anything'.

Please compile twice to get the correct heights.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox{cardbox}[1][]{%
  colback=white,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  width=5cm,
  #1,
}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4,raster equal height,boxrule=1pt, raster column skip=2pt, raster row skip=2pt]
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo bar
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}[colback=yellow]
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}
  \begin{cardbox}
    Foo
  \end{cardbox}

\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my installation (texlive 2013) I have `tcolorbox` from 2014/02/06 version 2.70, and it does not seem to have the `tcbraster` environment. I'll install a more recent version and will comment later. Compared to your example, I'd like for cards to span the whole width of the page and to not have the rules on the left and on the right. More importantly, I don't want to have horizontal double lines. Ideally the cards should be separated by a single line 0.4pt width. This line almost disappears when I cut the page with scissors.

Comment: @EvgenyMakarov: All those specifications are missing in your question, aren't they?

Comment: No, they are not. I said, "of size, say, text width times 5cm" and stipulated that the cards should be separated by a single, rather than double, line. Rules on the left and right are easy to remove, I assume, so they are less essential.

Comment: leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt, for example